# How to convert multiple plots into single plot?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a 10 curves whose x,y pairs are different and also number of points is different. How can I convert these 10 curves into one single curve in MATLAB?

EDIT: My code is very long. I can summarize problematic part like that:

`for (i=1:10) 
    [X,Y,T,AUC] = perfcurve(actual, predicted, 1); 
    plotroc(actual',predicted');
end`

I don't want 10 curves on one figure, but only one curve that is average of these 10 curves.

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: I edited the question text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help?  If you have A and B:

```
>> A = [1,2;3,4;5,6]

A =

     1     2
     3     4
     5     6

>> B = [7,8;9,10]

B =

     7     8
     9    10
```

Then you can merge them together:

```
>> C = [A;B]

C =

     1     2
     3     4
     5     6
     7     8
     9    10
```

Comment: Yes, but after this procedure what should i do? Maybe curve fitting I should use?

Comment: Based on your edited question, now I see that you want to average 10 curves together.  If each curve has the same number of datapoints, then you could just do (A+B+...)./10.  If they have different numbers of datapoints, then you could use interp1 to resample everything and do the same simple averaging.  Depending on your application though you may need to do something more complex, though.

Comment: I solved problem by using fit function of Curve Fitting Toolbox with "ploy6" parameter. Thanks